# Is automated detection of web forms, payment gateways, and ads on web pages possible?

Tags: web

I would like to know if it is possible to detect web forms, payment gateways, and ads on a web page in an automated manner, by running some code after crawling and indexing the web page.

To give the question some context, I would basically like to know if the given web page is being monetized in some way. If there were a program to detect the above, it would provide a way to find out if the web page is capturing leads, selling a product or service, or displaying ads.

Moreover, I would like to know: is there some form of on-page monetization that **cannot** be detected by using an automated program?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to parse a web page after downloading it - but if you need to ask the question then you still have a very long journey ahead of you before you are capable of understanding how to do this. Your question is also off topic as it does not relate to solving a programming problem.

However it is impossible to determine programatically if the content of a web page represents monetization. It is possible to make some guesses using a database of known advertisers and/or very advanced AI techniques. Come back and ask again after you have mastered data science, antagonistic / back progogated neural networks and image analysis in about 15 years from now.